# Ember Data - Many to Many Relationships?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The project I am working on relies heavily on many-to-many relationships, however I am unable to see how exactly to achieve this using Ember Data in Ember JS.

The use case I currently have is made up three models:

```
Person
Address
PersonAddress
```

The link between the person is necessary for what I am currently working on. Would it be possible to get an example of how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to manage the many-to-many relationship yourself using the intermediate `PersonAddress` model, which I assume holds a single person associated with a single address.

This is not a very good way to do things. To find a person's addresses, you're going to have to manually lookup all the entries in `PersonAddress` for that person, then take the addresses from those entries. The problem with this approach, among others, is that when a new address is added, for example, you will have to redo this lookup, and ensure that it happens automatically in order for the UI to be updated properly.

It is much better to simply have `hasMany` relationships on both Person and Address. Then Ember Data will keep everything in sync--something like

```
// models/person.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  addresses: DS.hasMany('address')
});

// models/address.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  address: DS.attr(),
  persons: DS.hasMany('person')
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my database schema uses this intermediate table to store details regarding the link. Are you saying that I can still have this setup but then in my web service manipulate the data to return as what you just said?

Comment: Just noticed you used hasMany in both models, I didn't think this was possible currently with Ember Data?

Comment: It has been possible to have hasMany in both models since Ember Data was born, and is the preferred way to handle many-to-many relationships. I don't care how your server is organized; some data sources on the server might prefer to have a model using intermediate table of relationships. You can use such a model as is in Ember, but it will be more work on the Ember side. It is preferable to have the web server provide and accept data in the standard Ember Data many-to-many form.